# WCF Bad Request. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I renamed service contract file in my **WCF** service and now there is an error when i try to add or update service reference:

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MessengerService/MessengerService/mex/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MessengerService/MessengerService/mex'.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MessengerService/MessengerService/mex'.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Service is deployed in **WcfSvcHost**.
My `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MessengerService.ServiceLogic.MessengerService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="MessengerService.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IMessengerService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MessengerService/MessengerService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

It's incredible. So, if i write this code in callback contract:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void MakePulse();
```

That's normal. But if i write this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void Pulse();
```

That's absolutely wrong.

Comment: you changes something else. this cant be true